# How to get the value of a specific row from a treeList

Tags: devexpress, treelist

```
DataRow dataRow = treeList1.GetDataRow(treeList1.FocusedNode.Id);
```

The id value exists, but the entire tree data appears in the data row, not a specific row.

I don't know what to modify or add